# Editing-like style in Lyx

Tags: lyx

Is it possible to achieve the below in Lyx (words above/under sentences)?

[image]

Comment: Yes, if you're willing to fork out some ERTs...

Comment: I am aware that I will have to go through that road.

Comment: You don't have to use ERT, see my answer below. LyX has come quite far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using `\overset`, found under `Frame decoration` in the `Math` toolbar.

[image: Well, I'm not going to do new screenshots now...]

In the `\overset`, you'll be in math mode, so you have to enter normal text mode (type `\mbox`, or use the same shortcut you entered math mode with). Then enter the text you want something under.

You have to do something similar for the upper box. The first thing I found that gets you a small font while italic was to enter text mode, then math mode again, and then choose `Script (small) style` from the `Styles` icon in the math tool bar. Space between words in math mode may be inserted using the `Math spaces` icon also in the math toolbar.
There may be a more elegant way to do it.

[image]

With a longer sentence over a single word, the words around will be pushed "out of the way" as the word in the lower box and the box above become one entity.
I handled this in two different way: In the second paragrapg, the `\overset` contains only `[the]`, and then I inserted a vertical space on each side, with a custom space of `-18pt`. In the third paragraph, the lower `\overset` box contains `operation [is the variety of] services` and the content of the upper is centered by insert a couple of math space before the text (start with `\phantom`, else they will be ignored.

The content of the .lyx file is below. If you just copy that into an empty file (or create a .lyx file and overwrite it's content), you should be good to go (except replace `families` with `households` ;) ). If not, clear out the preample (or install any missing package -- but that's just for the font).

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble    

\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-ams-bytype
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman charter
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 0
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 0
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 0
\use_package stmaryrd 0
\use_package undertilde 0
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2cm
\topmargin 2cm
\rightmargin 11cm
\bottommargin 2cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
Poor families pay more for 
\begin_inset Formula $\overset{\mbox{\ensuremath{{\scriptstyle their}}}}{\mbox{[the]}}$
\end_inset

 food [that they buy]
\begin_inset Newline linebreak
\end_inset

because local merchants exploit them.

\begin_inset VSpace defskip
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
This is a development 
\begin_inset space \hspace{}
\length -18pt
\end_inset


\begin_inset Formula $\overset{\mbox{\ensuremath{{\scriptstyle with\,\, indeterminate}}}}{\mbox{[the]}}$
\end_inset


\begin_inset space \hspace{}
\length -18pt
\end_inset

 social consequences [of which are indeterminiate].
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
(Or: This development has indeterminate social
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
consequences.)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\begin_inset VSpace defskip
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
Fundamental to our 
\begin_inset Formula $\overset{\mbox{\ensuremath{{\scriptstyle \phantom{{\}}}\,\,\,\, are\, our\, many\, community}}}}{\mbox{operation [is the variety of] services}}$
\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline linebreak
\end_inset

[that our company has to offer to the community].
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it is what you were looking for, then please mark it as an Accepted using the check mark on the top left :)

Comment: [Tool location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZblOP.png).